# read the value from registry rather than hard code in if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement

i have below powershell line. It will return 1 when there is account found in administrators group other than built-in administrator, group1, group2, group3.

```
If ((Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | Where-Object {($_.ObjectClass -eq 'User' -or $_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group') -and (($_.Name -notlike "$env:computername\administrator") -and ($_.Name -notlike 'group1')  -and ($_.Name -notlike 'group2')  -and ($_.Name -notlike 'group3') )}).Count -gt 0) {
echo 1
}else{
echo 0
}
```

how do i change the above if statement to read in the string value (which has commas) in registry so I don’t need to hard code group1, group2, group3 in the if statement?? Thanks

example i had set it at hklm:\system\test , named as adm and string value of group1,group2,group3

i am able to pull the value i set at registry using this line.

```
$listofadm = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\system\test" -ErrorAction Stop -Name adm).adm
```

Comment: `$listofadm[0]` shuold give you the first item in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are checking if user or group, if you can omit that it will simplify your check. To streamline this I would make a regex pattern of all the groups including the computer\adminsitrator account. If the groups indeed do not have a space then you can simply replace the commas with a pipe `|` character.

```
$listofadm = "$env:computername\administrator|" +
    (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\system\test" -ErrorAction Stop -Name adm).adm -replace ',','|'
```

This will make `$listofadm` contain something like

```
DESKTOP-NEKK74J\administrator|group1|group2|group3
```

Now if you just want to find any object whose name is not any of those 4

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | where name -NotMatch $listofadm
```

Single item checks in the Where clause can omit the `{ }` curly braces. If you do need to ensure it's a user or group object then this is how that would look.

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators |
    Where-Object {($_.ObjectClass -eq 'User' -or $_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group') -and $_.name -NotMatch $listofadm}
```